# When does all() function in Python print False?

Tags: python

```
x = [0, 1, -2, 3, 4, 5]
all ([i for i in range (1, len(x)) if x [i-1] < x[i]]) ?
```

Why does this code print `True`?
1 > -2 so it should print `False` I think.

Comment: Because the list comprehesion returns `[1, 3, 4, 5]` all the elements in this list evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does. It first filters out some elements, and then evaluates a bunch of indices for truthiness. Since all of the indices are strictly positive, they are all truthy and your code always evaluates to `True`.

From your description, what you're actually trying to do is this:

```
>>> all(x[i-1] < x[i] for i in range (1, len(x)))
False
```

This iterates over all pairs of consecutive elements and checks whether the first element is less than the second.

Another way to write this is:

```
>>> all(a < b for (a, b) in zip(x, x[1::]))
False
```

Comment: shouldn't `zip(x, x[1::])` be faster ? (no need to generate an extra copy of the first list). And you removed the [] without explaining why it was useless.

Answer (score 3):

All values of `i` come from `range(1, len(x))`, so they're all positive integers. Positive integers are true-ish, so `all()` will return `True`.

Comment: It's `True` because the list is **not empty**, regardless of the sign of the numbers inside it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun **Wrong!**. A list containing 0 (or something falsy) will not return `True` with `all`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Try `if [0]: print True`

Comment: @MarounMaroun Try `if all([0]): print True`

Comment: My mistake, changing my vote. Thanks for the correction everyone.